# Boto3 Object put method loads 0 bytes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

The following loads an empty file to my s3 bucket. Why?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[324,34,25], [463,23,43]])
out = df.to_csv(index=False) # unicode string (i'm in python 3)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
BUCKET = "MyBucketThatDefExistsAndIHaveAccessTo"
bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)
obj = bucket.Object('TEST1')
obj.put(df.to_csv(index=False)) # loads an empty file "TEST1" to my bucket.

# I've also tried, but same result.
obj.put(bytes(df.to_csv(index=False), 'utf8'))
```

Comment: Please read the Object.put() documentation: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should it not be,

> obj.put(Body=df.to_csv(index=False)) # loads an empty file "TEST1" to
>   my bucket.

Missing Body named parameter. Since first parameter is ACL, you need to specify the name.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just dumb. Needs the `Body=` kwarg.

`obj.put(Body=df.to_csv(index=False)` works